# Bash: adding directory names into array

Tags: bash

As title says, I want to add directory names into an array, but  can't figure it out how. This is what I have so far:

```
path=some/path/in/linux

declare -a categ_array

for d in ${path}/*; do
    #strip directory name of the path
     dir_name=${d##*/}

     #add the directory name into array
     categ_array+=("${dir_name}")
done

echo ${categ_array}
```

This code outputs only 1 directory name (doesn't matter how many directories i have).

Comment: `${categ_array}` expands to only the first element of the array. You should use `${categ_array[@]}` instead. Also, loop can be replaced with: `categ_array=("$path"/*)`.

Comment: @randomir You would want to follow up the initial assignment with `categ_array=( "${categ_array[@]##*/")` to strip the leading directory name from each element. Or, use `pushd "$path"; categ_array=(*); popd` to avoid adding it to each element in the first place.

Comment: @chepner, you're right, I missed the part where OP strips directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use this command to print all directories:

```
echo "${categ_array[@]}"
```

Though you can avoid loop and just use:

```
cd "$path"
categ_array=()
categ_array+=(*/)
```

examine the results:

```
declare -p categ_array
```